# Первая буква в словах предложения

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть такой код:

```
<div>good fool gol fuul reding fuul</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы искало слова, которые начинаются на букву *f*, и делало красной букву *f* со следующей буквой?

Comment: @Юра Спивак, практически все ваши вопросы из разряда: "Напишите код за меня". Поэтому традиционно: "*Покажите, что вы сделали сами и что именно не получается*"

Comment: Понимаете, я ничего не могу без этого сделать, покажите, как это сделать вообще?
___

Я не могу понять, как пользоваться запоминающими скобками в RegExp -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').html(function(e, html) {
    return html.replace(/(^|\ )(f.)/g, '$1<span style="color:red">$2</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>god fool golfs fuul reding fuul</div>
```

Comment: Что будете делать с такой строкой?

    "gofodf fool golf fuul reding fuufl"

Вам же надо: "*слова, которые **начинаются на букву f**, и делало красным букву f **и следующую букву** тоже*"

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Оно делает букву f и следующую букву красной.

Comment: @Юра Спивак, Ваш исправленный вариант чуть ближе к теме, и, если именно такой результат вы хотели, тогда забудьте. Просто для меня есть разница между тем, что вы написали в вопросе и тем решением, которые нашли. Опять придётся повторяться: "*слова, которые **начинаются на букву f***".